# Issue in configuring zpool ZFS in EC2

Tags: zfs, amazon-ec2

While executing  command in ZFS - `sudo zpool create -f alluxio /dev/xvda`  . Getting below error:`/dev/xvda is in use and contains a unknown filesystem`.
Could you please help me in solving this. Need urgent help.

Comment: What is the result `ls /dev/xvd*`?

Comment: [hadoop@ip- ~]$ ls /dev/xvd*
/dev/xvda  /dev/xvda1  /dev/xvdb  /dev/xvdb1  /dev/xvdb2

Comment: and what is the result of `mount |grep xvda1`?

Comment: Sorry for delay                                                                                                 
mount |grep xvda1
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this disk for `zfs` pool because the disk is used for root (`/`) filesystem and this is the place where your operating system is located.